# Is aubio cross-compilable for iPhone/Android/ARM?

Tags: iphone, audio, cross-compiling, aubio

Anyone know of:

1. A build of the [Aubio](http://aubio.org) library for iPhone/ARM processor?
2. An intro-to-cross-compiling resource so I can try it myself?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest git:

```
$ git clone git://git.aubio.org/git/aubio
$ cd aubio/
$ ./waf configure build --with-target-platform ios
```

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded in cross-compiling it without errors. I haven't tested the library itself, but the example executables seem to work, so that's a good sign!

The script I've put together (largely thanks to the invaluable information in [this link](http://cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2)) should work for a lot of other projects using Autotools (like Aubio's dependencies).

Note that both `libsndfile` and `libsamplerate` need a patch to cross-compile successfully, which I'm sure is ugly, but it works.

To use it, modify the script according to your system (should be pretty straightforward, I hope), download all the dependencies (listed in the `build xxxxx` lines at the end, your versions may vary) in the same directory as the script and run the script without arguments. At the end, everything should be inside the `$SYS_ROOT` directory.

Okay, the main dish is below :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Taken and improved from :
# http://cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2

# The designation for the host, usually "linux-x86" for standard linuxes, and
# "darwin-x86" for OSX.
HOST="linux-x86"

# The target architecture. Here we're compiling for ARM using GCC 4.7 and
# platform version 14.
TARGET_ARCH="arm"
TARGET_HOST="arm-eabi"
TARGET_TOOLCHAIN="arm-linux-androideabi"
TARGET_GCC_VERSION="4.7"
TARGET_NDK_VERSION="14"

# Add the toolchain to the path to be able to use the ARM compiler.
export PATH="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-$TARGET_GCC_VERSION/prebuilt/$HOST/bin:$PATH"

# Where to find the platform-specific files?
export PLATFORM="$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-$TARGET_NDK_VERSION/arch-$TARGET_ARCH/"

# Where to copy the platform-specific files?
# Will be used later as the target system root for cross-compilation.
export SYS_ROOT="`pwd`/sysroot/"

# Executable names for the compilation toolchain
export CC="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export CXX="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-g++ --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export CPP="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-cpp --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-ld"
export AR="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-ar"
export RANLIB="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-ranlib"
export STRIP="$TARGET_TOOLCHAIN-strip"

# Add the STLPort library to the search path (needed for C++ files)
export CXXFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/"
export LDFLAGS="-L$ANDROID_NDK/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/ -lstlport_static"

# Where to install the cross-compiled packages?
# When running `make install`, all the files (executables, libraries,
# documentation,...) will be in this directory.
export INSTALL_DIR="$SYS_ROOT/usr/"

# Where will pkg-config look for information about installed packages?
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="$SYS_ROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig/"

#################
# Configuration #
#################

# If the sysroot doesn't exist, create it and copy all the files from the NDK
# distribution.
if [[ ! -e "$SYS_ROOT" ]]; then
  echo "Creating sysroot [$SYS_ROOT]"
  cp -Rf "$PLATFORM" "$SYS_ROOT" || exit 2
fi

# If it doesn't exist, create the installation directory.
if [[ ! -e "$INSTALL_DIR" ]]; then
  echo "Creating installation directory [$INSTALL_DIR]"
  mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR || exit 3
fi

###############
# Compilation #
###############

build() {
  # Change directory to the package directory (in argument)
  echo "Building $1"
  pushd $1

  # Clean things up (optional)
  make clean 1>/dev/null 2>&1

  # Configure the package
  ./configure --host=$TARGET_HOST LIBS="-lc -lgcc" --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR || exit 1

  # Compile
  make || exit 1

  # Install in $INSTALL_DIR
  make install || exit 1

  # Return to the original directory
  popd
}

# Build all things
build libogg-1.3.0
build libvorbis-1.3.3
build flac-1.2.1
build libsndfile-1.0.25-patch
build libsamplerate-0.1.8-patch
build fftw-3.3.3
build aubio-0.3.2
```

**`libsndfile` patch**

```
--- libsndfile-1.0.25/programs/sndfile-play.c   2012-12-31 17:03:34.289908113 +0100
+++ libsndfile-1.0.25-patch/programs/sndfile-play.c 2012-12-31 17:04:05.326412364 +0100
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
 #if defined (__linux__) || defined (__FreeBSD_kernel__) || defined (__FreeBSD__)
    #include    <fcntl.h>
    #include    <sys/ioctl.h>
-   #include    <sys/soundcard.h>
+   #include    <linux/soundcard.h>

 #elif (defined (__MACH__) && defined (__APPLE__))
    #include <Carbon.h>
--- libsndfile-1.0.25/src/sndfile.c 2012-12-31 17:03:34.343241171 +0100
+++ libsndfile-1.0.25-patch/src/sndfile.c   2013-01-01 18:53:37.436544846 +0100
@@ -309,7 +309,7 @@
 {  SF_PRIVATE  *psf ;

    /* Ultimate sanity check. */
-   assert (sizeof (sf_count_t) == 8) ;
+   /* assert (sizeof (sf_count_t) == 8) ; */

    if ((psf = calloc (1, sizeof (SF_PRIVATE))) == NULL)
    {   sf_errno = SFE_MALLOC_FAILED ;
```

**`libsamplerate` patch**

```
--- libsamplerate-0.1.8/examples/audio_out.c    2011-07-13 01:57:31.000000000 +0200
+++ libsamplerate-0.1.8-patch/examples/audio_out.c  2013-01-01 17:24:58.257526888 +0100
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@

 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
-#include <sys/soundcard.h>
+#include <linux/soundcard.h>

 #define    LINUX_MAGIC     MAKE_MAGIC ('L', 'i', 'n', 'u', 'x', 'O', 'S', 'S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a build script that worked for me:

```
#! /bin/sh

"""
build the toold chain home with:
build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=../android-9-toolchain
"""

NDK_HOME=~/dev/SDKs/android-9-toolchain
set -x
set -e
export CC=$NDK_HOME/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CFLAGS=-I$NDK_HOME/include
export LDFLAGS="-L$NDK_HOME/lib"
export AR=$NDK_HOME/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar

./waf distclean
./waf configure --with-target-platform android --disable-jack
./waf build --verbose
./waf install --destdir dist-android
```

it will default to toolchain / gcc version 4.6, I changed this to 4.9 as that is the latest I have. 
it should pull down the libraries it needs to finish compiling

the main part of the script was kindly provided by Paul Brossier author of Aubio