# Aubio for BPM tracking on Android

Tags: android, c, audio-processing, aubio, beat-detection

I am working on a android audio project which requires BPM tracking. I decided that writing my own would not be a good idea and after looking around, I found a few libraries that does BPM tracking such as aubio, vamp, echonest etc. Out of the lot aubio seemed a good choice. The problem is I cannot find good documentation that can help understand how I can use the library, such as, what sort of input audio formats are compatible (should i pre-process the audio before passing it to the function), etc.

Can you point me to some documentations or implementations of aubio to some open source projects (on android would be a bonus).

If you think there is an easier way (another algorithm/library) to port on android (preferably in c), let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in updates, if you have any. I'm trying to cross-compile the whole thing, but it fails at a missing header...

Comment: Okay, now it works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791762/is-aubio-cross-compilable-for-iphone-android-arm/14112768#14112768 for more.

Answer (score 0):

I used the make files provided with aubio to cross compile it for android. I followed some tutorials such as [this](http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2/) which shows how to cross compile open source libraries. As for the documentation for aubio, i just used it several times to understand how it works (i studied how the examples worked) and read the phd thesis of the author to get a rough idea on the technical stuff.